# Facebook fan page read and reply private message

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get access the data `read` and `reply` private messages on facebook fan page using php? If it is possible, is there a link that I can learn how?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by private messages on fan page? If it is a fan page, there is no private message feature on a page.

Comment: @FurquanKhan I mean like this : http://s2.postimg.org/nyha0po89/fanpage.png

Comment: Please learn how to look through documentation yourself. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations